# Reducing visibility of the java interface when implementing it in an abstract class

Tags: java, oop

I have three interfaces as follows.

```
interface CFL extends PowerSaver, LightingDevice{
    void showLifeTime();
    void getBrand();
}

interface PowerSaver {
    void showEcoRate();
}

interface LightingDevice {
    void doLight();
}
```

Then I create a abstract class called Philips that implements CFL

```
public abstract class Philips implements CFL{
    void showLifeTime(){}; // Compiler says Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from CFL.
    void showEcoRate(){};  // Compiler says Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from CFL.
}
```

My question is why it says that I Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from CFL. while I haven't reduced it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface implementations must be `public`.

To understand the error, see the [spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html#36046):

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `public`.

Therefore, you're actually overriding (or, in this case, implementing) `public` methods.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. Got the answer. Assuming that the "Every method declaration in the body of an interface has implicitly package-default visibility" is my bad.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on [@SLaks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584810/139010), interface members in Java are always public — by default, or by using the `public` keyword. Anything else with cause a compile-time error. From [the JLS § 6.1.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#104285):

> All members of interfaces are implicitly `public`.

On the other hand, `abstract class` members (just like `class` members) have "package-private" visibility if no access modified is specified.

> ...We say there is default access, which is permitted only when the access occurs from within the package in which the type is declared.

That's why the compiler tells you that the methods in `Philips` have reduced visibility.

Comment: Thanks MДΓΓ БДLL. Got the answer. Assuming that the "Every method declaration in the body of an interface has implicitly package-private visibility" is my bad

Answer (score 1):

Interface declarations are always public - your implementation has made them package/default access.

Comment: Thanks Bedwyr Humphreys. Got the answer. Assuming that the "Every method declaration in the body of an interface has implicitly package-default visibility" is my bad.